# java - obj.notify() doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, deadlock, notify

In my java code the threadB creates *nb**threadA and waits until the value of *myobj* will be equal to *nb*. 
*myobj* is initially equal to 0 and each threadA increments it, when it becomes equal to *nb* the last threadA notifies the ThreadB.

When running the program the threadB is not notified and doesn't continue running. Could anybody tell me where is the problem in this code?

```
public class Myclass {
    static Long myobj = new Long(0);
    static int nb = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadA[] threadA = new ThreadA[nb];
        ThreadB threadB = new ThreadB(threadA);
    }
}

public class ThreadA extends Thread {
    public ThreadA() {
        this.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        // do lot of computation
        Myclass.myobj = Myclass.myobj + 1;
        if (Myclass.myobj.intValue() == Myclass.myobj.nb) {
            synchronized (Myclass.myobj) {
                Myclass.myobj.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ThreadB extends Thread {
    ThreadA[] threadA;

    public ThreadB(ThreadA[] threadA) {
        this.threadA = threadA;
        this.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < threadA.length; i++) {
            threadA[i] = new ThreadA();
        }

        synchronized (Myclass.myobj) {
            while (Myclass.myobj.intValue() != Myclass.myobj.nb) {
                Myclass.myobj.wait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. When you create ThreadB you give it a empty array with a certian size, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're waiting on one object, and notifying on a different one, since ThreadA assigns a new object to Myclass.myobj and notifies this new object.

Use a dedicated lock object, and make sure EVERY access to myObj is guarded by this lock object.

Or better yet, use higher-level concurrency abstractions from the java.util.concurrent package.

Comment: that's what I suspected. I will try with lock object.. hope it will not be so complicated. otherwise it isn't possible to do it correctly only with wait() and notify() ?

Comment: It is possible, like programming a web app in assembler. Higher-level abstractions make life simpler and safer.

Answer (score 9):

I was confused by all the things which could be wrong but didn't cause the problem.

The real problem is that

```
if (Myclass.myobj.intValue() == Myclass.myobj.nb)
```

will never be true as the every time this is called `myobj` < `nb`

---

How would I write this code?

```
int nb = ....

ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nb)
for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
    es.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do lot of computation
        }
    });
es.shutdown();
es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

---

There are so many things to improve here I feel the need to list them

- do use proper formatting.
- do provide code which might compile
- don't lock on a mutable field.  This won't do what you expect as you will be locking on a different object each time.
- don't use a `Long` when you mean to use `long`. In this cause you appear to want to use a `int`.
- don't create a `new Long(0)` as you can use autoboxing which would be more efficient. If you do this don't use it as an object to lock on.
- don't use a mutable `static` field between threads.
- don't extend `Thread`. Create a Runnable which is passed to a thread.
- don't start a thread in a constructor.
- don't use an array to pass a thread to another thread. esp as it won't be set until after that thread has started.
- only read/check protected values inside the synchronized block.
- I wouldn't use one thread to create another thread which is passed back to the original thread.

However, your basic problem is that you are waiting on a different object to the one you are notifying on.

```
synchronized(Myclass.myobj){ // lock the object you might be waiting on.
    Myclass.myobj=Myclass.myobj+1; // change this to another object.
    Myclass.myobj.notify(); // notify a different object.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answer... The first problem that you mention was a mistake I made when editing my question (it's corrected now). For the last problem you mention I don't understand why  Myclass.myobj=Myclass.myobj+1; changes the object to another one and how to increment the value of myobj without changing it ?

Comment: Ok, it still won't work due the other reasons I mentioned. ;)

Comment: Some mentioned points aren't obvious for me. For example if I want to share a same variable btw my threads I don't know how to it without using a mutable static field.

Comment: The simplest way is to create a mutable object before you create both threads. Pass this object in the constructor to both `Runnable` used by the threads and it will be shareable.